# Angular Hybrid Approach, AngularJS and Angular9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular9, angular-hybrid

I'm pretty new to the hybrid approach and Angular JS. I have a requirement to migrate few screens of AngularJS project(existing) to Angular9.

Current AngularJS project is using contoller based angularjs v.1.4 , GULP as task runner and SASS for CSS.

Can you please let me know how can I have the base application in AngularJS and integrate few screens of Angular9. Step by step procedure to have both JS and 9 work together.

any suggestions would greatly help.

Comment: There is a huge difference in two, here it is impossible to do. May be you can read some articles and slowly migrate it.

Comment: May I know why it is not possible to migrate? Is it because angular js is controller based?

Comment: I didn't say that it's not possible, I said it's impossible to guide you here. It will be better to look at examples online, understand and do this slowly, as there is huge difference between AngularJS and Angular2+.

Comment: Moreover you have not provided any code which makes us even more difficult.

Comment: I need high level overview on considerations for migration and how to have Angularjs application as base and add angular 9 into the angularjs application. Approaches is what I need. I dont have any code as of now. I have read articles but they say how to convert angular js files to ts and add those ts files into Angular 9 application, that way Angular 9 would be the base application right. I want to have angularjs as base application and include my Angular9 ngmodule in Angularjs config file. Is that possible?